# How can I prevent browser access to the js and css directories?

Tags: apache-2.2

What Apache directive would be appropriate to prevent browsers and spiders from exploring css, image and js directories on an Apache web server?

I found this in the http.con file, but it is not doing what I thought it was supposed to do:

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html/myhome/js">
  Options -Indexes
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Indexes means it will prevent directory listing, so if someone just enter 
yoursite.com/js

will not see ALL files in that folder. If you set it properly in httpd.conf, it should work.

Also you can put a simple blank index.html in each folder. Then again your all js files will not be listed.

If you want search engines do not index files in those directories, you have to add that directory in robots.txt disallowed urls list.